# Replacing 'Multiple' with different values in multiple columns with VBA macro in Excel

Tags: replace, macros, find, cell

I have the text "Multiple" in various cells in my sheet. I would like to replace the word Multiple with another word. But, the word I'm replacing Multiple with is different for each cell. I have found the below code to use.

For i = 1 To 100000

```
 With Sheets("Data")

    If .Range("I" & i).Value = "Multiple" Then _

    .Range("I" & i).Value = "Test"

End With

Next i
```

The above works great. However, I need to add multiple ranges to be replaced with different values. How do I add that?

For example,

The value of column I, J and K were originally "Multiple" but now I need to replace Multiple with the value in the picture. Each column is a different value. How do I add that in the above code?

[All the columns that have the value Multiple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZPQu.png)

[Replace multiple with a different value in each of the column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvgtx.png)

I hope all that made sense. Thank you!

I can only replace one column and not multiple columns.